# Custom animation doesn’t work

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to download file with custom animation. But when I use first code animation doesn’t work

**First code**

ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PWMainView *mainView; // custom animation view
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.mainView = [[PWMainView alloc] init];
[self.mainView.progressView setProgress:0];
[self.view addSubview: self.mainView];

_session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    [self.progressView setProgress:0 animated:NO];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;{

    [self.progressView setProgress:totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated:YES];

}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Warning.png"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];


NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

float progress = [urlData length]/(float)[urlData length];
[self.mainView.progressView setProgress:progress];

if (!fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"!fileExists");
}

if (fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"fileExists");
}


}

-(IBAction) downloadButton:(id)sender
{
if (_HighScore == 1) {
    if(_downloadTask == nil){


        _url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/ios-png-6.png"];

        _downloadTask = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url];

        [_downloadTask resume];

    }

    else

        [_downloadTask resume];
}
    [_downloadView removeFromSuperview];
    [_downloadButton removeFromSuperview];
    [_downloadButtonCancel removeFromSuperview];

}
```

If I use second code animation work. But I need to use the first code.

**Second code**

ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PWMainView *mainView; // custom animation view
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.mainView = [[PWMainView alloc] init];
[self.mainView.progressView setProgress:0];
[self.view addSubview: self.mainView];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chapter1.mp3"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_mHRsv5WQu6d3plcTlHV2VmaGs";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        float progress = [urlData length]/(float)[urlData length];
        [self.mainView.progressView setProgress:progress];

    });
}
```

Why animation doesn’t work in first code?

**Update**

Change line in code. Doesn’t work.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
{
  [self.mainView.progressView setProgress:progress];
}
```

But if I change link in firs code

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/ios-png-6.png";
```

on

```
NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_mHRsv5WQu6d3plcTlHV2VmaGs";
```

Everything is working. But animation is not performed throughout the downloading process. Only at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate methods of NSURLSession are called on a background thread. You must do UIKit calls from the main thread.

You nee to wrap any UI calls you do in those delegate methods in a call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. (Well, there are various ways to call UI code on the man thread, but this is a good one.)

Change this line:

```
[self.mainView.progressView setProgress:progress];
```

To

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
{
  [self.mainView.progressView setProgress:progress];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Update my question. When I use first code with default `progressView` animation is work. Maybe need to fix this line? `[self.progressView setProgress:totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated:YES];`

Comment: All of your `NSURLSession` delegate methods get called on a background thread, and all calls that update the UI need to be done on the main thread. Thus you need to wrap ALL your calls to `setProgress` that are done from delegate methods in calls to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` as shown in my answer.